# Forming compound words in Latin: helicopter

Tags: vocabulary, morphology, derivation

I would like to understand the formation of Latin compound words through the example of the word "helicopter".
This obviously has a Greek origin, and I would like redo the construction with two Latin words.

I would translate *helix* as *vertex* and *pteron* as *ala*.
But how do I combine the two analogously to the Greek *helico-pteron*?
I'm not sure what to do with the first word.
Can I go with *vertici-ala*?
Or is this a situation where natural compounds are impossible although Latin does allow compound words?

Comment: I won't try to write Greek letters on the phone. If someone dislikes Latinised Greek, feel free to edit.

Comment: [What's wrong with _helicopterum_?](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopterum)

Comment: @luchonacho I wanted to study the formation of such words in Latin, not find a Latin translation for a helicopter per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essence of the 'helicopter' idea is a rotating wing. The only possible words for wing here are *ala* and *aliger*, and I can think of two possibilities for introducing the 'rotatory' part. The adjective *versatilis* suggests the idea of a turning motion, while the noun *turbo* is used for any violent circular motion.

Accepting that any wing must imply the necessary lifting through the air, and that *versatilis* has less indication of force than *turbo*, this all leads me to propose *turbinaliger*, 'bearer of a fast-spinning wing' — which describes a helicopter quite neatly.